Python Testing With Similar Filenames
I have a project structured like
functions/
  function1/
    app.py
    tests/
      __init__.py
      test_app.py
  function2/
    app.py
    tests/
      __init__.py
      test_app.py

Which encounters the error HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules.
AFAIK it recurses to the first directory without an __init__.py (in this case functionX directory) and imports from there meaning they're both pathed as tests.test_app.py.
Is there any way to get around this without adding __init__.py's to functionX dir or renaming stuff?
Hoping to have inline testing with different top level dirs but same structure in each subdirectory

Why not just rename the test files (e.g., test_function1_app.py, test_function2_app.py)?

I would prefer to have each module layed out exactly the same with app.py as the entrypoint and test_[file].py as the tests. That way if they're ever seperated for example there isn't an arbitrary naming convention inherited.
That being said changing the filenames is likely what I'll do if I can't find a more "graceful" solution

What is the command you are issuing to run the tests? And what directory are you in when you run the tests?

I'm inside functions (ls would return function1 function2), I'm just running pytest
If it helps pytest function1 & pytest function2 seperately both work

Does this pytest issue help? https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3151#issuecomment-1693832968

Sadly this different import mode has the same issue
